# How can I use now() in Doctrine 2 DQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

```
$ php app/console doctrine:query:dql 'SELECT NOW()'
```

> [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
>    [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'now'

How can I use MySQL's `NOW()` function with Doctrine's DQL?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The equivalent of MySQL's `NOW()` is Doctrine DQL's **`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`**.

`CURRENT_DATE()` only returns the date part.

Reference: [DQL date/time related functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#line-number-c2439321397191dde881faa94a3a33ab0aeff984-14)

Comment: I am not sure but it is not working for me. It returns `s0_.available_on >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: @KonradGałęzowski No, MySQL's `NOW()` returns `2019-11-29 18:19:37` and Doctrine's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` returns `2019-11-29 18:19:37`.

Comment: @Benjamin sorry, you're right. Got cunfused by another error message in my query.

Answer (score 2):

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() uses database timezone, which could lead to weird issues.
More simple way - you can use parameter and bind new \DateTime() to it (so you will use php timezone)

It will not work for command line of course, but I suppose that you plan to use it in controller/service/repository/etc..