# YEAR(CURDATE() in DQL (Doctrine Query Language)

Tags: symfony, dql

In `MySQL` there is `YEAR(CURDATE()`.

```
mysql> SELECT YEAR(CURDATE());
+-----------------+
| YEAR(CURDATE()) |
+-----------------+
|            2017 |
+-----------------+
```

How to obtain it in DQL? In directly usage

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('s')
   ->where('s.year = YEAR(CURDATE()');
```

I obtaining:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 105: Error: Expected known function, got 'YEAR'
```

I trying

```
SUBSTRING(CURDATE(),1,4);
```

that again works correctly in pure MySQL, but in DQL I have now error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 115: Error: Expected known function, got 'CURDATE'
```

Similar results give:

```
SUBSTRING(NOW(),1,4);
```

I mean it works in MySQL, but in doctrine end with exception:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 115: Error: Expected known function, got 'NOW'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would have to add some extra functions to doctrine.

Here is the link for some that would give you what you need.
https://github.com/luxifer/doctrine-functions.

However you would probably best using a php DateTime Object or date() to get the current year as pass that in as a parameter
e.g.

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('s')
->where('s.year', date('Y'));
```

Comment: I see that it is your first answer there. Great start!. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found answer:

To obtain current year in doctrine use:

```
SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(),1,4)
```

Source

> [How can I use now() in Doctrine 2 DQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347872/how-can-i-use-now-in-doctrine-2-dql)