# Comparing current date with stored dated on doctrine querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I need to make a query  to get the row where  the active field is true or the current date is between two stored dates Itring with

```
 $qb->andWhere('p.active = true')')
                ->orWhere($qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->lt('p.activationDate', 'now()'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('p.deactivationDate', 'now()')
                ))
            ->setMaxResults(1);
```

But I get :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 145: Error: Expected known function, got 'now'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use now() in Doctrine 2 DQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347872/how-can-i-use-now-in-doctrine-2-dql)

Answer (score 0):

the were can be like this:

```
->andWhere("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN p.activationDate and p.deactivationDate")
```

like this:

```
$repo = $this->em->getRepository(YourRepo::class);
$result = $repo->createQueryBuilder("p")
    ->andWhere("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN p.activationDate and p.deactivationDate")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```